# Rails: file nested fields, show the name of file selected on each field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using the `cocoon gem` in order to add images with nested fields:

```
<div id="attachments">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :attachments do |attachment| %>
    <%= render 'products/attachment_fields', form: attachment  %>
    <% end %>
        <div class="links" id="add_attachment" style="display: inline; float: right;">
           <%= link_to_add_association 'add more images', f, :attachments, form_name: 'form' %>
         </div>
</div>
```

And this is the partial.... _attachment_fileds.tml.erb:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= form.label :image, required: true %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="custom-file" style="padding-top: 38px;">
        <%= form.input :images, label: false, as: :file, :input_html => { :class => 'custom-file-input', :style=>"cursor: pointer", :id=>"inputGroupFile01"} %>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01" id="file-name" style="cursor: pointer;">Choose file</label>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div style="text-align: right;"><%= link_to_remove_association "remove", form %></div>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine.

Now, regarding each field that is generated with `cocoon` I would like to replace the `choose a file` text from the label field  with the name of the file that  has been selected.

At first I tried the following but I then figured that the `cocoon gem` generates a different id for each field.

```
<script>
  $("#inputGroupFile01").change(function(){
      $("#file-name").text(this.files[0].name);
  });
</script>
```

So now I'm kind of stuck on how to implement the above. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An html-id is supposed to be unique on the page, so you cannot use a unique id for a repeating field. While the page may render correctly, when posting the form it will ignore duplicate id's (and thus will post incorrect/incomplete information).

Secondly, using jquery it is pretty easy to just find the closest element.

So in your partial for the nested fields remove all id's, so write something like

```
<%= form.input :images, label: false, as: :file, 
      :input_html => { :class => 'custom-file-input', :style=>"cursor: pointer"} %>
<label class="custom-file-label" style="cursor: pointer;">Choose file</label>
```

And then you can write something like (untested obviously)

```
$(".nested-fields .custom-file-input").change(function(){
  $(this).siblings("label.custom-file-label").text(this.files[0].name);
});
```

There are a few options, and I am not sure which selector works the best. You could go up, and then select the correct label:

```
 $(this).closest('.nested-fields').find('label.custom-file-label')
```

I am not sure if just looking for the `closest` label would work?

```
 $(this).closest('label.custom-file-label')
```

Or as I did above, look for the `sibling` with the correct selector.